# Entity Framework 7 Rollback method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How to roll back an transaction in Entity Framework 7?

In the old version, we have

```
            try
            {
                dataContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
                dataContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                dataContext.Database.CurrentTransaction.Rollback();
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

Now I use

> "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"

It doesn't have the method.

Comment: But SaveChanges runs already in transaction under the covers. So if SaveChanges fails - that transaction rolls back.

Comment: @Evk, in old EF, does `SaveChanges` have covered transaction failure. If so, why there was `Rollback` method invented?

Comment: Yes as far as I know it was always wrapped in transaction. As for why there is Rollback - you can start transaction explicitly via dataContext.Database.BeginTransaction(). Then you can for example call SaveChanges multiple times. If you would want to rollback that - you will need to call Rollback.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended transaction pattern in `7.0.0-rc1-final` is the same as in EF6:

```
using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        /*do something*/
        context.SaveChanges();

        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Also EF7 provides async API (EF6 not):

```
using (var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync())
```

Comment: Currently [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) says "transaction will auto-rollback when disposed if either commands fails"